# Instance member 'logEvent' cannot be used on type 'AppEvents'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: swift, facebook, fbsdk

I have used Facebook AppEvents in which I am getting error:-

```
AppEvents.logEvent(.completedRegistration, parameters: [AppEvents.ParameterName.registrationMethod.rawValue: "customerId"])
```

Answer (score 3):

`AppEvents` class from Facebook is now singleton class, so to use the methods of `AppEvents` class you have to add shared between class and method name so solution for this is use:

Instead of using `AppEvents.logEvent` use `AppEvents.shared.logEvent`.

```
AppEvents.shared.logEvent(.completedRegistration, parameters: [AppEvents.ParameterName.registrationMethod.rawValue: "customerId"])
```

Also, please remove `.rawValue` to avoid error `Cannot convert '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[AppEvents.ParameterName : Any]'`.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817044/setadvertisertrackingenabled-is-not-found-in-settings-class-of-fbsdk/71723749#71723749).